# Retrieve Jetty from Maven Central Repository as project dependency in IntelliJ IDEA Project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetty

I want to use Jetty as an embedded library in a Java project I'm working on in IntelliJ IDEA.  However, there are many different packages for Jetty available from the Maven Central Repository.  The JAR available for direct download from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/) is named as `jetty-distribution-9.0.3.v20130506.tar.gz`, so I assumed the best complete package available from the Maven Central Repo was `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-distribution:9.0.3.v20130506`.  But IntelliJ returns this error when attempting to use that coordinate to retrieve the library:

> No files were downloaded for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-distribution:9.0.3.v20130506

Why can't that package be found?  And if it's not usable, which packages should I download?

**Edit:** <s>I now realise that the coordinate I should have been using is `org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all:9.0.3.v20130506`.  I can locate this at [`search.maven.org`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty.aggregate%7Cjetty-all%7C9.0.3.v20130506%7Cjar), but IntelliJ cannot find anything newer than version 7.  Can anyone reproduce or explain this issue?</s> Moved to new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the dependency type.

There are so called **pom** type of dependencies, which act as a list of other dependencies. To be able to fetch them, you have to mark them as pom dependencies in your pom.xml

If you only need the server component, try searching for this string

```
'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.0.3.v20130506'
```

Comment: Would that be this line of the pom file: `<packaging>pom</packaging>`?

Comment: Yes and no :) quick test for my answer is to. Just try to add <type>pom</type> to the jetty dependency declaration

Comment: Okay, do you know how to access the pom file for a dependency added through the IntelliJ GUI?

Comment: Edited my previous comment

Comment: I've done a search in my project directory, and there is no `pom.xml`.  I'm assuming that's because my project is not a Maven one - I'm just using Maven to retrieve libraries.

Comment: then try to add it as <packaging>pom</packaging> to the IntelliJ Idea

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31453/discussion-between-mtcoster-and-funtik)

Answer (score 0):

Maven dependencies have a `type`, which by default is `jar`. The jetty distribution package is not a jar, and as [you can see in the central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22jetty-distribution%22%20g%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty%22), you can download either a `.zip` or a `.tar.gz`, so you'll have to declare the dependency as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-distribution</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

If you build now, it will download the zip and the build will probably succeed. But, a zip is different from a jar, so depending on what you're actually doing in that build, you will have to do more things to actually make use of that zip.

You probably don't want to use the distribution package unless you're also building a standalone distribution (.zip) for your project as well, in which case you should probably use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) which can unzip the jetty distribution and rezip your whole project.

What you should do is decide what exactly you're going to need and build a custom jetty. Here's the starting point, enough to be able to deploy a simple servlet-based application:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-xml</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-deploy</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You're probably going to need this one as well, since this is how you can start Jetty:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-start</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Look at [the list of modules](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty%22) to see what else you might need, for example `jetty-ajp`, `jetty-websocket`, or `jetty-jsp`.

Comment: If you read the comments above, you'll see that I don't have a `pom.xml` to put any of this into - I'm just using IntelliJ's ability to download libraries from Maven Central.